# adding elements to an Entity object java

Tags: java, list, opencsv

I have a Java program that runs by getting data from a database into a `List` of `Entity`s. We use an entity class, `Customer`, and a `List<Customer>`.

I now have data coming from a log file. I will need to construct a `List<Customer>` using this data.

How can I do this?

Currently, I have

```
List<Customer> c1= cDao.getAllElements(SQL);
// process c1
```

I am reading the log file which has very similar data elements using OpenCSV, an open source file parser.

I want to create a similar `List`, say:

```
List<Customer> c2 = getElementsFromLog();
```

Is there a way I can build such a `List<Customer>`? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Customer> c2 = new ArrayList<Customer>(); //Or any other class implementing List
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    Customer c = new Customer(nextLine); //Or create a new Customer in some way
    c2.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement getElementsFromLog. I am assuming there is a file that is available. You will open it, read the lines, and build a Customer object by parsing the line of data. There is no answer I can give you more than this. The rest comes down to your requirements and details of your log/Customer entity.